# Regex group does not catch brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have following regex:

```
Word:(\(?<term>\)[a-zA-Z()]*)
```

If I pass `(Word:Arm)` it will capture `Arm`, but if I want to pass `(Word:(Arm))` it does not match a thing. I need this second case to capture `(Arm)`, brackets included.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Edit your question, use backticks `\`` to surround your regex pattern. Then you will not get unexpected output (spaces)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match the parenthesis at all, you can exclude them in the character class.

To match the balanced parentheses, instead of making one optional you can use an alternation matching with or without parenthesis.

Using a case insensitive pattern with `/i`

```
const regex = /Word:(?<Term>\([a-z]+\)|[a-z]+)/i;
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ztN1S/1)

```js
const regex = /Word:(?<Term>\([a-z]+\)|[a-z]+)/gmi;
const str = `(Word:Arm)
(Word:(Arm))`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(m.groups["Term"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need this group match < term >, so that in the end I have "groups" in regex exec result. 
So for input '(Word:(Arm))' i need new Regexp.exec(pattern) to have groups property in which i will have this 'term': '(Arm)'

Comment: @FilipT I have added an example and the group name to the pattern.